# Copy Tablerow and Add it

Tags: c#, ms-word, row

I'm working with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (*v14.0*).

I have a word document.
In that word document I created a **table** with **3 Columns** and added **1 row** to the table.

Each of the 3 cells in the first row are containing a **field**. When the user press print button on my Window/Form I take the informations (positions, with 3 attributes in my UI context) and use Microsoft word template, my word document that has this row with the 3 cells to be filled with these info coming from WPF Window / (same as Windows Forms).

Actually, the problem is, I don't know how I can **copy an existing tablerow**. The quantity of positions (describing one Row), can be **different** and I search a way, how to **copy an existing row, with these 3 fields in it and add it just at the bottom. Or an other way would be, to create a row, and these fields, foreach cell, dynamically..** Anyway

How can I do that?

Well, adding rows doesn't seem to be a problem (Code from MSDN):

```
object beforeRow = this.Tables[1].Rows[1];
this.Tables[1].Rows.Add(ref beforeRow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: something like this might work: I'm not sure what should be passed as the `Range` parameter to `Fields.Add` though.

```
object beforeRow = this.Tables[1].Rows[1];
Row newRow = this.Tables[1].Rows.Add(ref beforeRow);

Field fld = beforeRow.Cells[0].Range.Fields[0];
Range range = fld.Range; // newRow.Cells[0].Range ?
newRow.Cells[0].Range.Fields.Add(ref range, ref fld.Type, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: I have fields in my cells. I'm not writing directly into the cell. I need to copy a Row, with the 3 fields in the row (1 field for 1 cell). Or the other way: Creating a new Row, these 3 Cells, 1 Field foreach Cell, and give this Field a Name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Range.Copy()` Method.

```
Row beforeRow = this.Tables[1].Rows[1];
beforeRow.Range.Copy();
beforeRow.Range.Paste();
```